# format date from "M/D/YYYY HH:mm:ss" to "YYYY/MM/dd HH:mm" vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, date, format

How to format  date from "M/D/YYYY HH:mm:ss" to  "YYYY/MM/dd HH:mm" javascript ?
Exemple:
from '6/15/2018 09:15:00'  to "2018/06/15 09:15"

```
const formatDate = () => {
  //
  return;
};
formatDate(new Date('6/15/2018 09:15:00')) // "2018/06/15 09:15"
```

Comment: Is it possible to use moment.js?

Comment: If the use of moment.js is allowed, take a look at this demo https://codepen.io/vyspiansky/pen/RwprvjK

Comment: Just split it into parts and rearrange them. All the data you require is in the original string, no need for parsing to a Date and formatting.

Answer (score 0):

In the function `formateDate` , what you have to do is to concatenate all year, month, date hours and minutes in a string.

And in the function `precedingZero` , `slice` only takes the last two digits from `num` parameter.

That is what following code does

```js
function formatDate(dateObj)
{
    var dateString = dateObj.getFullYear() + "/" + 
                     precedingZero(dateObj.getMonth()+1) + "/" + 
                     precedingZero(dateObj.getDate()) + " " + 
                     precedingZero(dateObj.getHours()) + ":" + 
                     precedingZero(dateObj.getMinutes());
    return dateString;
}

function precedingZero(num)
{
    return ("0" + num).slice(-2); // slice take the last two digits from num parameter.
}

var newFormattedDateString = formatDate(new Date('6/15/2018 09:15:00')); // "2018/06/15 09:15"

console.log(newFormattedDateString);

document.getElementById("dateTimeShow").innerHTML = newFormattedDateString;
```

```html
<div id="dateTimeShow"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything you need is in the original timestamp, so just split it into parts and reformat it, e.g.

```js
// '6/15/2018 09:15:00' to "2018/06/15 09:15"
function reformatTimestamp(s) {
  let z = v => v.padStart(2,0);
  let [m,d,y,H,M,S] = s.split(/\D/);
  return `${y}/${z(m)}/${z(d)} ${H}:${M}`;
}

console.log(reformatTimestamp('6/15/2018 09:15:00'));
```